# How to kill a process which is create by popen and uses communicate()?

Tags: python, subprocess, kill, popen, terminate

I have a program, `P1`, which I need to run about 24*20000 times with different inputs. The problem is the `P1` hangs and I should force it to quite manually (`kill`). My first solution was writing a python script to call `P1` and passing the proper input and receiving the output using `popen` and `communicate`. But due to the nature of communicate which waits for the output, I can not kill the process as long as it is waiting for the response. I am on Windows.

I tried to use `multiprocess` function, but it only runs the `P1` and failed in sending the input to it. I am suspicious about not using pipes in `popen` and tried a little bit but I guess I can't receive the output from `P1`.

Any ideas?

```
# This code run XLE and pass the intended input to it automatically
 def startExe(programPath, programArgStr):
 p = subprocess.Popen(programPath,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE) p.stdin.write(programArgStr)
 p.communicate()[0]
# Need to kill the process if it takes longer than it should here

def main(folder): 
.. 
#loop
programArgStr = "create-parser"+path1+";cd "+ path2+"/s"+ command(counter) +";exit"

startExe(path, programArgStr)
..
```

As you can see if P1 can finish the given task successfully it can exit itself, using the exit commands passed to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by editing current code and putting the killer code in a separate file.
to do that I add a line to write PID of the newly created process in a file.

```
    #//Should come before p.commiunicate
    WriteStatus(str(p.pid) + "***" + str(gmtime().tm_hour) + "***" + str(gmtime().tm_min))        
    p.communicate()[0]
```

And the process monitor executed seperately and checks every 2 mins to see if the processes listed in the file are still active. If yes kill them and remove their ID.

```
 def KillProcess(pid):

    subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /PID "+ str(pid) + " /F /T" , shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /im WerFault.exe /F /T" , shell=True)
    print "kill"

    def ReadStatus(filePath):
    print "Checking" + filePath
    try:
            status = open(mainPath+filePath, 'r').readline()
    except:
            print "file removed" + filePath
            return 0
    if len(status) >0:
            info = status.split("***")                
            time = [gmtime().tm_hour, gmtime().tm_min]
            print time

            # Time deifferences
            difHour = time[0]- int(info[1])
            if difHour == 0: # in the same hour
                    difMin =  time[1]- int(info[2])
            else:
                    difMin = 60 - int(info[2]) + time[1]
            if difMin > 2:
                    try:
                            open(mainPath+filePath, 'w').write("")
                            KillProcess(info[0])
                    except:
                            pass
    return 1

  def monitor():
    # Read all the files
    listFiles = os.listdir(mainPath)
    while len(listFiles)>0:
            #GO and check the contents
            for file in listFiles:
                    #Open the file and Calculate if the process should be killed or not
                    pid = ReadStatus(file)
                    #Update listFiles due to remove of file after finishing the process '
                    # of each folder is done
                    listFiles = os.listdir(mainPath)
            for i in range(0,4):
                    time.sleep(30) #waits 30 sec
                    subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /im WerFault.exe /F /T" , shell=True)
    #to indicate the job is done
    return 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not required to use Python, you might consider using Cygwin Bash along with the [`timeout(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command to run a command with a timeout.  However, since Cygwin's implementation of `fork()` is not very fast and you're creating an enormous number of processes, you'll likely have an enormous overhead of just creating processes (I don't know if the native Windows version of Python is any better in this regard).

Alternatively, if you have the source code to `P1`, why don't you just modify it so that it can perform multiple iterations of whatever it is that it does in one invocation?  That way, you don't have to deal with creating and killing 480,000 processes, which will make a huge difference if the amount of work that each invocation does is small.

Comment: ACTUALLY I DON't have access to P1 source code. I can just execute it. I didn't get exactly what I can do with CygWin. Could you please explaoin me more? THe following is some bits of my code.
<code>
# This code run XLE and pass the intended input to it automatically

def startExe(programPath, programArgStr):
 p = subprocess.Popen(programPath,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
 p.stdin.write(programArgStr)
 p.communicate()[0]
 
        
def main(folder):
..
programArgStr = "create-parser"+path1+";cd "+ path2+"/s"+ command(counter) +".txt;+";exit"

Comment: I tried to edit my question so could you please help me with that again?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `popen`, you can specify either a pipe or file descriptor to accept stdout from the process:

> Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, **stdout=None**, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)

You can then monitor the file/pipe you pass to popen, and if nothing is written, kill the process.

More info on the popen args is in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Rather than using `p.communicate`, try just looping through the lines of output:

```
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print ">>> " + line.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
from threading import Thread
def main(input):
    #your actual program, modified to take input as argument
queue = ['Your inputs stored here. Even better to make it to be a generator']
class Runner(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while len(queue)>0:
            input = queue.pop()
            main(input)
        return True
#Use 24 threads
for thread in xrange(24):
    Runner().start()
#You may also join threads at the end.
```

Of course this approach would introduce some vulnerabilities, like "two threads pops queue list at same time", but I never encountered it in real-life.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to my input program :(